# How to correctly display a multi - criteria dataset on a heatmap?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a dataset in a numpy array in the below format. Each "column" is a separate criteria. I want to display a heatmap where each "column" would correspond to the score range within that column:

`[[ 226      600   3.33    915.     92.6    98.6 ]
  [ 217      700   3.34    640.    93.7    98.5 ]
  [ 213      900   3.35    662.    88.8    96.  ]
  ...
  [ 108      600    2.31   291.     64.     70.4 ]
  [ 125      800    3.36   1094.    65.5    84.1 ]
  [ 109      400    2.44   941.     52.3    68.7 ]]`

I have written a function to generate a heatmap:

```
def HeatMap(data):

    #generate heatmap figure
    figure = plt.figure()
    sub_figure = figure.add_subplot(111)
    heatmap = sub_figure.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest',cmap='jet', aspect=0.05)

    #generate color bar
    cbar = figure.colorbar(ax=sub_figure, mappable=heatmap, orientation='horizontal')
    cbar.set_label('Scores')

    plt.show()
```

This is what the function generates:

[image]

As per above, it can be seen that the problem lies in my function somewhere as the `Scores` range from 0 to a maximum value in the dataset of 2500. How can I amend my function so that the heatmap displays the scores in the columns according to their range rather than the range of the whole dataset? My first thoughts are to change the array dimensions to something like `[[226],[600]] etc.` but not sure if that's the solution

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a separate `cmap` for each column.

If you want to see the variation in each column as per their own range, you can `normalize` the data by column before plotting the `heatmap`.

**Code**

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1000,  10,   0.5],
              [ 765,   5,  0.35],
              [ 800,   7,  0.09]])

x_normed = x / x.max(axis=0)

print(x_normed)
# [[ 1.     1.     1.   ]
#  [ 0.765  0.5    0.7  ]
#  [ 0.8    0.7    0.18 ]]

# Plot the heatmap for x_normed.
```

This will preserve the variation in each column.

Comment: Thanks. Would normalizing the data be standard practice when plotting multi - criteria data? I thought of having multiple colorbars corresponding to individual score ranges when the precise ranges are of concern. But I guess it's viable until hundreds of bars show up and everything becomes a mess.

Comment: Yes, It's the standard practice to deal with `continuous data` for plotting as well for modelling.